# indeed scrapy can't retrieve data

Tags: scrapy

I run this command scrapy crawl indeed --logfile=crawl.log But no logfile is generated and I received the following error. I tried to debug the code, can't see nothing.

```
enter code here`File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 110, in execute
settings = get_project_settings()
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 295, in setmodule
self.set(key, getattr(module, key), priority)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 270, in set
self.attributes[name].set(value, priority)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 55, in set
value = BaseSettings(value, priority=priority)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 91, in __init__
self.update(values, priority)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 327, in update
for name, value in six.iteritems(values):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 587, in iteritems
return iter(d.items(**kw))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The issue seems to come from your settings.

Comment: I wonder, they don't recognize the class items, but I am not sure since the message seems different.

import sys
sys.path.append("D:\\pythoncode\\crawlers\\scrapy-indeed-spider")
from indeed.items import IndeedItem